# Synchronization issue with running linux commands in the background

Tags: linux, synchronization, background-process

I have to run three blocking linux commands(command1, command2 & command3) and I implemented synchronization so that if user runs command2 using terminal2 while command1 is executing in terminal1 my server returns an error saying command1 is still executing. Same for command3. But If I do a loop like below

```
for i in {1..3}; do { command$i & }; done
```

All three start executing parallel which is undesired. Is it a synchronization fault or I shouldn't run those commands this way? Is running commands in the background not same as running them in different terminals?

I feel I am missing something obvious here. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand is putting the jobs in the background, which returns immediately and has the effect of running them in parallel.  To run them in series, remove the &.

Comment: I understand that. But my question is why are they starting at all? Is it my synchronization fault? If I try running command2 using a different terminal while command1 is still executing I get expected error saying command1 is still executing.

Comment: It's possible job 2 is starting before whatever synchronization you are doing in job 1 is established.  Gist?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't want them to run sequentially. My question is purely about enforcing synchronization so they fail when run in parallel. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I have a synchronized(this) where they start execution. Is it not enough?